# Why can an empty numpy array have a multidimensional dimension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I noticed a "strange" behaviour (at least for me) by reducing a numpy array to a zero size. Let's look at the following example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> b = a[:,-2] == 2
>>> b
array([False, False])
>>> a[b]
array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=int32)
```

a[b] is - as expected - an empty array, but its shape is (0, 4). However, I expected a shape of () or (0) or (0,). I tested this on Python 3.8.8 and Python 3.10.9, same behaviour. Is this a feature or a bug?

I often work with files that contain either one or multiple lines and need to be read as an array. This leads to different scenarios where the file may have no entries, a single entry, or multiple entries. Each new entry corresponds to a new line. So far, I have always used len(data.shape) for this purpose. If the file contains a single line, then len(data.shape) = 1. If it contains at least two entries, then len(data.shape) > 1. However, this approach no longer works as len((0, 4)) = 2. Is there a better method than checking the values of shape to handle this situation?

Comment: Think of it like a table that has no rows, but it still has column headings that indicate the number of columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. So, it is completely normal and intentional that the shape does not change to (0,)?

Comment: Right. This new array is derived from the previous array, so it copies the number of columns and just filters the rows.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. That clears up all my questions.

Comment: Any dimension of an array can be 0.  It won't have any elements, but all the shape numbers remain significant.  numpy does not try to condense or otherwise reduce the number of dimensions.

Comment: While `[]` and `isempty` is a meaningful test for lists, numpy really doesn't have a special category of 'empty array'.  The function `np.empty` has nothing to do with a 0 dimension.